# aligning left and right in same line dynamically asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net

I am Displaying Picture dynamically in gallery ,below picture i displayed product name,product weight , product color, product quality,origin and quantity.It is currently displayed in 6 lines,each item per line...
I want to display two items in each line and 6 item in 3 lines.First item should align left , second item on right on first line and so on.how can i do it? this is my code.

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class jewellery : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void select_data()
    {
        //String con_str = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\asim\bootstrap1 (1)\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        String con_str = @"Data Source=KHAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=D:\ASIM\BOOTSTRAP1 (1)\APP_DATA\DATABASE.MDF;Integrated Security=True";
        //string con_str = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\project\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_str);
        con.Open();
        string query = "select * from jewellery1";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int n = 1;
        String id = "Image";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl section = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("section");
            section.ID = "portfolio";
            section.Attributes["class"] = "bg-light-gray";
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl row = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            row.Attributes["class"] = "row";
            Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])reader["item_image"];
            String item_name = (String)reader["item_name"];
            String color = (String)reader["item_color"];       
            String weight = (String)reader["item_weight"];
            String quality = (String)reader["item_quality"];
            String clarity = (String)reader["item_clarity"];
            String origin = (String)reader["item_origin"];


            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            createDiv.ID = "createDiv" + n + 11;
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv1 =
      new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl hover = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            hover.Attributes["class"] = "portfolio-hover";
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl hover_content = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            hover_content.Attributes["class"] = "portfolio-hover-content";
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl i = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("i");
            i.Attributes["class"] = "fa fa-2x";
            createDiv1.ID = "createDiv" + n + 12;
            createDiv1.Attributes["class"] = "col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item  zoomIn animated";
            createDiv1.Attributes["data-wow-duration"] = "1500ms";
            createDiv1.Attributes["data-wow-delay"] = "100ms";
            createDiv.Attributes["class"] = "portfolio-caption";
            LinkButton a = new LinkButton();
            a.Attributes["class"] = "portfolio-link";
            a.Attributes["data-toggle"] = "modal";
            a.Click += new EventHandler(test);
            a.CommandArgument = item_name;
            /* System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl a = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("a");
             a.Attributes["class"] = "portfolio-link";
             a.Attributes["data-toggle"] = "modal";*/
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl h1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("h4");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl h2 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("h4");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl h3 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("h4");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl h4 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("h4");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl h5 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("h4");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl h6 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("h4");



           
                h1.Attributes["align"] = "LEFT";
                h1.Attributes["style"] = "color:black";
                h1.InnerHtml = "Name &nbsp &nbsp :&nbsp &nbsp  " + item_name;
                h2.Attributes["align"] = "RIGHT";
                h2.Attributes["style"] = "color:black";
                h2.InnerHtml = "color  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp :&nbsp &nbsp " + color;
            
            h3.Attributes["align"] = "LEFT";
            h3.Attributes["style"] = "color:black";
            h3.InnerHtml = "Weight &nbsp &nbsp: &nbsp &nbsp " + weight;
            h4.Attributes["align"] = "LEFT";
            h4.Attributes["style"] = "color:black";
            h4.InnerHtml = "Quality   &nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp  " + quality;
            h5.Attributes["align"] = "LEFT";
            h5.Attributes["style"] = "color:black";
            h5.InnerHtml = "Clarity   &nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp  " + clarity;
            h6.Attributes["align"] = "LEFT";
            h6.Attributes["style"] = "color:black";
            h6.InnerHtml = "Origin   &nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp  " + origin;

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl hyp = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            hyp.Attributes["class"] = "portfolio-link";

            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image tb = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image() { ID = "Image" + n + 10 };
            tb.Height = 250;
            tb.Width = 500;
            tb.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            hover_content.Controls.Add(i);
            a.Controls.Add(hover);
            a.Controls.Add(hover_content);
            a.Controls.Add(tb);
            createDiv.Controls.Add(h1);
            createDiv.Controls.Add(h2);
            createDiv.Controls.Add(h3);
            createDiv.Controls.Add(h4);
            createDiv.Controls.Add(h5);
            createDiv.Controls.Add(h6);
            createDiv1.Controls.Add(a);
            createDiv1.Controls.Add(createDiv);
            // row.Controls.Add(createDiv1);
            //section.Controls.Add(row);

            divid1.Controls.Add(createDiv1);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                reader.GetString(1));
            n++;
        }
    }
    protected void test(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String wagerId = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument;
        Response.Redirect("awesome.aspx?eid=" + wagerId);

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            select_data();
        }

    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

**Updated Code**
Bro your code didn't work. I tried this way,its working somehow fine . It displays H1  on left ,H2  on right.thats fine but it also displays h3 in center,as it should be on next line.how can I resolve it.

```html
 h1.Attributes["class"] = "links left";
                h1.Attributes["style"] = "color:black";
                h1.InnerHtml = "Name &nbsp &nbsp :&nbsp &nbsp  " + item_name;
                h2.Attributes["class"] = "links right";
                h2.Attributes["style"] = "color:black";
                h2.InnerHtml = "color  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp :&nbsp &nbsp " + color;
               

            h3.Attributes["class"] = "links right";
            h3.Attributes["style"] = "color:black";
            h3.InnerHtml = "Weight &nbsp &nbsp: &nbsp &nbsp " + weight;
            h4.Attributes["align"] = "LEFT";
            h4.Attributes["style"] = "color:black";
            h4.InnerHtml = "Quality   &nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp  " + quality;

  <style>
.mainlinks
    {
    text-align:right;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }

 a.links:link {
    color: #FF0000; text-decoration: none;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-top:300px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:2px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    }
 
.right { float: right }
.left { float: left }

</style>
```

Comment: When I do this  h2.Attributes["align"] = "Right",                h2.Attributes["align"] = "LEFT" disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. I've removed **Attributes["align"] = "LEFT"** part and added **float: left;width: 50%;**. Adjust the width percentage according to your needs.

```
h1.Attributes["style"] = "color:black;float: left;width: 50%; ";
 h1.InnerHtml = "Name &nbsp &nbsp :&nbsp &nbsp  " + item_name;

 h2.Attributes["style"] = "color:black;float: left;width: 50%; ";
 h2.InnerHtml = "color  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp :&nbsp &nbsp " + color;

 h3.Attributes["style"] = "color:black;float: left;width: 50%; ";
 h3.InnerHtml = "Weight &nbsp &nbsp: &nbsp &nbsp " + weight;

 h4.Attributes["style"] = "color:black;float: left;width: 50%; ";
 h4.InnerHtml = "Quality   &nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp  " + quality;

 h5.Attributes["style"] = "color:black;float: left;width: 50%; ";
 h5.InnerHtml = "Clarity   &nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp  " + clarity;

 h6.Attributes["style"] = "color:black;float: left;width: 50%; ";
 h6.InnerHtml = "Origin   &nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp  " + origin;
```

**UPDATE (Commented out the variables for adjusting in my VS)**

```
var n = 1;
            while(n < 5) { 
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                createDiv.ID = "createDiv" + n + 11;
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv1 =
          new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl hover = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
                hover.Attributes["class"] = "portfolio-hover";
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl hover_content = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
                hover_content.Attributes["class"] = "portfolio-hover-content";
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl i = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("i");
                i.Attributes["class"] = "fa fa-2x";
                createDiv1.ID = "createDiv" + n + 12;
                createDiv1.Attributes["class"] = "col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item  zoomIn animated";
                createDiv1.Attributes["data-wow-duration"] = "1500ms";
                createDiv1.Attributes["data-wow-delay"] = "100ms";
                createDiv.Attributes["class"] = "portfolio-caption";
                LinkButton a = new LinkButton();
                a.Attributes["class"] = "portfolio-link";
                a.Attributes["data-toggle"] = "modal";
                //a.Click += new EventHandler(test);
                //a.CommandArgument = item_name;
                /* System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl a = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("a");
                 a.Attributes["class"] = "portfolio-link";
                 a.Attributes["data-toggle"] = "modal";*/
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl h1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("h4");
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl h2 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("h4");
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl h3 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("h4");
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl h4 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("h4");
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl h5 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("h4");
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl h6 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("h4");





                h1.Attributes["style"] = "color:black;float: left;width: 50%; ";
                    h1.InnerHtml = "Name &nbsp &nbsp :&nbsp &nbsp  " + "item_name";

                h2.Attributes["style"] = "color:black;float: left;width: 50%; ";
                    h2.InnerHtml = "color  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp :&nbsp &nbsp " + "color";


                h3.Attributes["style"] = "color:black;float: left;width: 50%; ";
                    h3.InnerHtml = "Weight &nbsp &nbsp: &nbsp &nbsp " + "weight";

                h4.Attributes["style"] = "color:black;float: left;width: 50%; ";
                    h4.InnerHtml = "Quality   &nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp  " + "quality";

                h5.Attributes["style"] = "color:black;float: left;width: 50%; ";
                    h5.InnerHtml = "Clarity   &nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp  " + "clarity";

                h6.Attributes["style"] = "color:black;float: left;width: 50%; ";
                    h6.InnerHtml = "Origin   &nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp  " + "origin";

                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl hyp = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
                hyp.Attributes["class"] = "portfolio-link";

                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image tb = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image() { ID = "Image" + n + 10 };
                tb.Height = 250;
                tb.Width = 500;
                tb.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," /*+ Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)*/;
                hover_content.Controls.Add(i);
                a.Controls.Add(hover);
                a.Controls.Add(hover_content);
                a.Controls.Add(tb);
                createDiv.Controls.Add(h1);
                createDiv.Controls.Add(h2);
                createDiv.Controls.Add(h3);
                createDiv.Controls.Add(h4);
                createDiv.Controls.Add(h5);
                createDiv.Controls.Add(h6);
                createDiv1.Controls.Add(a);
                createDiv1.Controls.Add(createDiv);
                // row.Controls.Add(createDiv1);
                //section.Controls.Add(row);

                divid1.Controls.Add(createDiv1);
                n++;
            }
```

Comment: still I got the same result .It prints every product details in different lines.I want two products in each line.

Comment: The answered code works well when you talk about alignment. check out this screenshot in my localhost: http://imgur.com/HQFSyvW

Comment: `float: left;width: x%;` is the only change you need to do in your style. Either do it inline or via class. I can see your update, but it won't work that way, it's haphazard.

Comment: Glad for you. Can you please mark this as correct answer.